# Name points inside a feature made with Geometry.MultiPoint

Tags: google-earth-engine, multipoint

i am trying to name the points inside a feature build with a ee. Geometry.MultiPoint function as shown in the image. This points are alredy named in the imports place. But to build this feature a used just lat and long information.

[image]

I can´t use a Feature Collection, because this function below needs a feature or a image to run properly.

```
var featureCollection_getvalue__wet_2000 = 
ee.FeatureCollection(getvalue__wet_2000.slice(1).map(function(singleData){
  singleData = ee.List(singleData);
  var dict_getvalue__wet_2000 = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys_getvalue__wet_2000, singleData);
  //var point = ee.Geometry.Point([dict.get('longitude'), dict.get('latitude')]);
  //var timeFormat = ee.Date(dict.get('time')).format('YYYY-MM-dd');
  return ee.Feature(geometria, dict_getvalue__wet_2000); //.set('timeFormat', timeFormat);
}));
```

This function makes it possible to export the results as a list. But without the names in the points the identification of the results is a little difficult.

The results in the exported table are a sequential, but without mentioning who it is at which point.

Does anyone knows who to name the points to see the results with this names?

Comment: I am a little confused regarding 'name' of the feature. Are you referring to the variable name or a property that is within the feature? It would be great if you could share a working link as well since that might give a better idea.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think what need is set a name as property foe each point . Because de variable is the group of points ("geometria") .  Here is the link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/ef20b7c1475681ef0ead23840179c0a0